# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\log(1+x^{-1})$

Tags: limits

Can someone help me out with $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\log(1+x^{-1})?$$ I tried Taylor's expansion to no avail.

Comment: Hint: for large $x^{-1}$ the 1 becomes negligible. Eliminating it, you return to a familiar problem...

Comment: $x \rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: @Ian, yes, you are right.  Not sure how that makes the problem simpler.  What is the familiar problem you are hinting at?

Comment: No. $\log$ is undefined for negative values.

Comment: @mjw I was thinking of pulling out the exponent and then taking the limit of just $x\log(x)$. Changing variables works too, of course.

Comment: That's why I asked below if L'Hopital is still applicable. Because it usually applies to functions that are differentiable in the open interval around the limit point.

Comment: @Ian, yes!  That does come up all the time ($\lim x \log x $).  Thanks!

Comment: Well, if a function only has a limit from the right, we can use L'Hopital's rule from the right.  If we look at the derivation of L'Hopital's rule, it should be clear that we can limit it to one side.

Comment: mjw. Has been discussed already. $\log a$ is defined for $a>0$. $x \rightarrow 0^-$ would lead to a negative argument in $\log (1+1/x).$

Comment: @PeterSzilas, agreed.  Was discussed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\downarrow 0}x\log(1+x^{-1}) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=0$$

by L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Does L'Hopital apply to limits of the form $ x\rightarrow 0^+$? (Because the limit in my question is from the right).

Comment: left and right limits at 0 are not equal for this function. Use the right-side limit.

Comment: Yes.  Here is a reference:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html

Comment: Is that why you changed the limit to $x\rightarrow \infty$ so that the numerator and denominator become differentiable in any open interval as $x$ goes to infinity?

Comment: No, actually, we could have applied L'Hopital's rule to $\lim \frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}.$  I made the change-of-variables $w=1/x$ because the derivative is a little easier in both numerator and denominator.

Comment: Okay, using notation to indicate we are taking the limit from the right.  Thanks for pointing out this subtlety.

Comment: mjw. Well done.

Comment: @PeterSzilas, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log(1+x^{-1})=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log(x^{-1}(x+1))=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log(x+1)-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log x = 0-0=0$$

We know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log x=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log x}{\frac{1}{x}} $ using L'Hopital's rule

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\log x = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{\frac{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}=\frac{x+1}{x}=1$$

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

By $1+\frac1x=y \to \infty$ we have

$$x\log(1+x^{-1})=\frac1{y-1}\cdot \log y=\frac y{y-1}\cdot \frac{\log y}y \to 1\cdot 0 =0$$

using that eventually $\log y\le \sqrt y$.