# Why does $\lim_{x\to0} \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1$?

Tags: limits

> Why does $\lim_{x\to0} \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=1$?

Beware that I am NOT asking about $ \lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x $, which I know equals to $e$.

When you draw it in GeoGebra or WolframAlpha, it tells us that this is true.

But WHY?

Any help (or better, proof) is welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3551494/42969

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ops sorry! I read wrongly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x\log(1+x^{-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551494/calculate-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-0x-log1x-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left({1 + \frac{1}{x}}\right)^x=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{x\ln\left({1 + \frac{1}{x}}\right)}=^{t=\frac{1}{x}}\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}=1$$

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{t+1}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

First, let's notice that $\lim_{u \to +\infty}\frac{u}{2^u} = 0$ (which should be obvious). This implies the existence of $U(\varepsilon > 0) : \forall u > U(\varepsilon), \frac{u}{2^u} < \varepsilon$.

Second, let's see that $\lim_{x \to 0}(\frac{1}{x})^x = 1$: if it were $1 + 2\varepsilon$, we could take $x = 2^{-u}, u > U(\log_2(1+\varepsilon))$ and get $(\frac{1}{x})^x = 2^\frac{u}{2^u} < 2^{\log_2(1+\varepsilon)} = 1 + \varepsilon$.

Finally, let's deal with $1+\frac{1}{x}$: $(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x} = [(x+1)(\frac{1}{x})]^x = (x+1)^x\cdot(\frac{1}{x})^x$ and limits of both multipliers as $x \to 0$ are $1$s.

(All the logic above assumes $x>0$: $(1 + \frac{1}{x})^x$ is usually considered ill-defined for real $x \in [-1,0]$; notice that sequences like $(-2n)^\frac{-1}{2n+1}$ converge to $-1$ for pretty much the same reason.)

The underlying logic of solution, of course, is backwards: first you see there should be little difference between $(1 + \frac{1}{x})$ and $\frac{1}{x}$, then you try some "large" $\frac{1}{x}$, like $2^n$ and get $2^\frac{n}{2^n}$, then you prove that the latter converges to 1 and retrace steps in a "proper" proof.